# What can i use if i want an instant messaging app in android?

Tags: java, android, chat

I need an advice guys.
I want to connect two or more android device and exchange messages. what can i do to accomplish this?
Can I use Google Cloud Messaging, Network Service Discover, even through WiFi, etc..
Any advice is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the XMPP-Protocol, which allows to exchange messages between different devices. It is stable and used by Google (Talk, Hangouts), too: http://xmpp.org/

There are various libraries for different languages (including android) that you can use: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/